# upgraded to latest nx workspace, test fail with transform

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, ts-jest, ecmascript-2020, nx-workspace

We are upgrading angular with nx workspace to latest
The problem is when we run test, we got following errors

```
feature-flag.mjs:93:20: ERROR: Transforming for-await loops to the configured target environment ("es2015") is not supported yet
feature-flag.mjs:184:4: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("es2015") is not supported yet
```

The feature-flag library was build es2020, and our current App also on es2020 after upgrade.
The app using the feature-flag lib test fails with the error

I am not sure how to fix it
Things I have tried, in the App I have adjust tsconfig, tsconfig.app, tsconfig.spec to es2015 or es2017, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Zeo (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5843339/zeo)?